# What's wrong with DVD burning?

Tags: dvd, burning, k3b

I hadn't burned any DVDs in a while and today I needed to burn 3 of them from 3 different iso files. 2 very small ones (a few Kb) and one very large (8G, double layer). They all failed within seconds of starting on two different kubuntu systems using K3b. The small ones had unspecified I/O errors, the large one:

```
Burned media
DVD+R Dual Layer

Devices
HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GS40N A100 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

System
K3b Version: 2.0.2 KDE Version: 4.13.3 QT Version:  4.8.6 Kernel:      3.13.0-35-generic

Used versions
growisofs: 7.1

growisofs
Executing 'builtin_dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0' /dev/sr0: splitting layers at 1987888 blocks /dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 4.1x1352KBps.
          0/8142389248 ( 0.0%) @0x, remaining ??:?? RBU 100.0% UBU   0.0%
=== last message repeated 18 times. === :-[ WRITE@LBA=0h failed with SK=0h/ASC=00h/ACQ=03h]: Input/output error :-( write failed: Input/output error

growisofs command:
/usr/bin/growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/dev/fd/0 -use-the-force-luke=notray -use-the-force-luke=tty -use-the-force-luke=4gms -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:3975776 -use-the-force-luke=dao:3975776 -dvd-compat -speed=6 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m
```

It was my last double layer DVD...

Maybe I should add the following from dmesg:

```
warning: `growisofs' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
CDB: 
Write(10): 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00
ata4.00: cmd a0/01:00:00:00:80/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 30 dma 32768 out
         res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
ata4: hard resetting link
ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
ata4: EH complete
ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
CDB: 
Start/Stop Unit: 1b 00 00 00 02 00
ata4.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 16
         res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
ata4: hard resetting link
ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
ata4.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
ata4: EH complete
```

Comment: As a troubleshooting/diagnostic step, does the same problem occur when booting from an Ubuntu Live CD?

Comment: If I boot from a livecd, then I can't use the drive to burn a DVD...

Comment: Oops - interesting observation!  Guess you could try a live USB.  But that may be a bit of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

> exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen

This indicates hardware problems with the SATA connection
to the drive.

Traditionally one would advise to check cabling and power
supply. But i see traces in the web, that bad other hardware
(e.g.network) can cause this:
  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1052099#p1052099

(Enter above error message to Google to see lots of different
 reports with different theories about the reason.)

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

Comment: I really don't see any link between my problem and that post. I'm on a very recent high-end Dell (and also an older Dell). I was thinking either of a problem in those ISO files or some recent bug in K3B...